# Confirm action with password in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication, django-1.5

How can I create a "confirm with password" form in Django 1.5? I am going to make a function to disable the user account, but the account shouldn't be disabled if the user can't provide the correct password. I've tried with a FormView and `form_class=AuthenticationForm`, but it shows both the username and password, and I want only the password, because the user is already logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a password validation form:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password

class ValidatePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label="Your Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ValidatePasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        valid = check_password(password, self.user.password)
        if not valid:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid password')
        return password
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

from myapp.forms import ValidatePasswordForm

@login_required
def validate_password(request):
    form = ValidatePasswordForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something upon validation
            # disable account
            pass
    request_dict = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
        request_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```